# WPF bar chart in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, bar-chart

I am looking for a WPF MVVM friendly way of achieving [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2197/Custom-DataGrid-with-Progress-Bar-control).

Comment: Please provide the relevant pieces of the link in your question and also show what you have tried so far. Links can go bad over time.

Answer (score 1):

you should try Live charts, all charts are animated and chart updates when data changes.

https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

here is an example, of course you can set use code behind to make it more powerful, you should check included examples in that library

```
<liveCharts:BarChart Name="Chart" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <liveCharts:BarChart.Series>
            <liveCharts:BarSeries Title="Maria"    PrimaryValues="20, 40, 45, 60, 55, 60, 65, 70"></liveCharts:BarSeries>
            <liveCharts:BarSeries Title="John"     PrimaryValues="30, 35, 43, 68, 65 ,70, 55, 60"></liveCharts:BarSeries>
            <liveCharts:LineSeries Title="Averge"  PrimaryValues="25, 37.5, 44, 64, 60, 65, 60, 65" AreaOpacity="0"></liveCharts:LineSeries>
        </liveCharts:BarChart.Series>
        <liveCharts:BarChart.PrimaryAxis>
            <liveCharts:Axis Name="PrimaryAxis" Title="Sold Items"></liveCharts:Axis>
        </liveCharts:BarChart.PrimaryAxis>
        <liveCharts:BarChart.SecondaryAxis>
            <liveCharts:Axis Title="Month" Labels="Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Ago, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec"></liveCharts:Axis>
        </liveCharts:BarChart.SecondaryAxis>
    </liveCharts:BarChart>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid with 2 columns for progress bar and with converter set grid column width. Sum of both column must be 1*.
For example for 60% first column will have 0.6* and second 0.4*.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <local:ProgressConverter x:Key="ProgressConverter" />
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Progress, Converter={StaticResource ProgressConverter}, ConverterParameter=First}" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Progress, Converter={StaticResource ProgressConverter}, ConverterParameter=Second}" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Background="Green" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Progress, StringFormat=P}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

...

```
public class ProgressConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            double progress = (double)value;
            if ((string)parameter == "First")
            {
                return new GridLength(progress, GridUnitType.Star);
            }
            else if ((string)parameter == "Second")
            {
                return new GridLength(1 - progress, GridUnitType.Star);
            }
        }
        return new GridLength(0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public double Progress { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "David", Age = 23, Progress = 0.42 },
            new Person { Name = "Joe", Age = 42, Progress = 0.82 },
            new Person { Name = "Barry", Age = 31, Progress = 0.69 },
        };
    }
}
```